# How to install multiple php version without apache?

Tags: php, php-fpm

So far I am using PHP 7.*. I have been running php without apache installed.

```
sudo apt install php php7.2-cgi
```

Then you can run

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

Now, I want to install `8.0`

Is is possible to install both 7 & 8 php without apache. I found examples which require apache to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can install PHP without Apache. 99% of the time people will be using PHP with either Apache or nginx, which is likely why you cannot find much where it's just PHP alone.

If PHP 8.0 is not available for your specific distribution (as it's currently not part of your question), you can use the ondrej/php PPA:

```
sudo apt install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

From there, install the version(s) of PHP that you would like:

```
sudo apt install php8.0
```

Be sure to grab any additional modules that you might need, as these are version specific. For example, if you are connecting to a MySQL database, working with JSON, and doing everything from the command line or shell scripts, then you'll want to do this:

```
sudo apt install php8.0-cli php8.0-mysql php8.0-json
```

Once all of the modules are installed, you'll need to use `update-alternatives` to specify which version of PHP you are calling from the command line:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.0
```

Confirm this with:

```
php -v
```

When you want to go back to 7.2 (or any other version of PHP), call `update-alternatives` again with the version that you need to use.

Hope this answers your question

Comment: Thanks. I could install both 7 & 8 now.